# Get kotlin sealed class name heirarchy

Tags: kotlin

I wrote a dirty function that gives me the name structure of a sealed class heirarchy.
It sucks because its using reflection - so i'm asking if there's a better, non reflective way.

```kotlin
fun KClass<*>.sealedClassName(): String {
    var className = simpleName
    var sealedParent = superclasses.firstOrNull { it.isSealed }
    while (sealedParent != null) {
        className = "${sealedParent.simpleName}.$className"
        sealedParent = sealedParent.superclasses.firstOrNull { it.isSealed }
    }
    return className ?: qualifiedName ?: jvmName
}

    interface AnInterface
    open class AnClass
    sealed class Grandparent : AnClass(), AnInterface {
        sealed class Parent : Grandparent(), AnInterface {
            object Child : Parent()
        }

        object AuntieObject : Grandparent()
        data class UncleData(val x: Int) : Grandparent()
    }

    @Test
    fun sealedClassName() {
        check(Grandparent.Parent::class, "Grandparent.Parent")
        check(Grandparent.AuntieObject::class, "Grandparent.AuntieObject")
        check(Grandparent.UncleData::class, "Grandparent.UncleData")
        check(Grandparent.Parent.Child::class, "Grandparent.Parent.Child")
        check(Unit::class, "Unit")
    }
```

Comment: it's not dirty and can't be done without reflection. its the only way. reflection is not bad btw!

Comment: Why do you need to do this anyway? Sealed classes are really a way to group some classes and objects into a common type, they're not for creating structures - I feel like there's probably a better way to do what you're aiming for (like creating a ``Person`` class that can have a child ``Person`` and a parent ``Person``, that kind of thing). If you make use of types in your data structures, you won't need to check types with reflection

Comment: The reflection in the function has a negative impact on CPU usage in my case.

Comment: I've inherited a redux-observable based app, and to log events flowing through the app, its useful to know the heirarchy. Say you have 5 'Success' events, with different parents, its useful to see UserEvents.GetUser.Success(props) instead of Success(props) when you call toString(). Now i know i could call my events UserEvents.GetUser.GetUserSuccess() or similar but i was wanting a cleaner way. Hey ho, i tried :)